# Ruby bundler make binary

Tags: ruby, makefile, bundler, gnu-make, freebsd

I'm using Ruby on FreeBSD and I have difficulty compiling native extensions due to them needing GNU make instead of FreeBSD's make. Any idea how can I force gmake to be the default compiler for bundler without alias/PATH-fu?

Comment: any reason in particular why alias/PATH-fu is to be avoided?

Comment: alias doesn't work as system() (extconf.rb) doesn't honor aliases. I could do it by setting a PATH in which the gmake binary is copied as make and has precedence over FreeBSD make, but it seems like a bit stupid solution to me.

A bundler configuration option would be very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting a MAKE environment variable pointing to gmake?

Comment: Thats the *exact* way to do it. Set the MAKE environment variable. Bundler making some configuration option would be useless if your environment is not honoring the basics of the program's use. (make (both the gnu & bsd varieties) was designed with its use in mind).

This indicates you have an issue with your system. If it won't honor setting the environment var MAKE, then its also not honoring system variables. Thats how both FreeBSD, Linux, and most other Unices set, change, or otherwise modify. I would strace or turn on debugging. See whats' going on. Thats NOT normal behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking the same thing. Actually during the configuration steps it is correctly showing the MAKE path, but not in extconf.rb. I needed a quick solution, so I used the way RVM sets the PATH environment variable and executed
ln -sf /usr/local/bin/gmake ~/.rvm/bin/make